# R list as key for hash

Tags: r, vector, hashmap

I am using the `hash` library and would like to use a vector as the key, however, it wants to assign to each of the values in the vector, but I want to use the vector itself as the key. How can I set and access the hash elements to achieve this? I would like to do something like this:

```
library(hash)
h <- hash()

inc <- function(key) {
  if(has.key(c(key), h)) {
    h[[key]] = h[[key]] + 1
  } else {
    h[[key]] = 1
  }
}

inc(c('a', 'b'))
```

And have the key `c('a', 'b')` and value `1` in the hash. Whenever I pass the same vector, then the value is increased by one.

I understand this is a normal behavior in R since it is an array programming language, but I would like to avoid it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea: you can use [`deparse()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/deparse.html) to produce an unambiguous string representation of the input argument, which will be a valid hash key. Theoretically this could work on any R object, not just atomic vectors.

```
library(hash);
h <- hash();

hinc <- function(key.obj) { key.str <- deparse(key.obj); h[[key.str]] <- if (has.key(key.str,h)) h[[key.str]]+1 else 1; };
hget <- function(key.obj) { key.str <- deparse(key.obj); h[[key.str]]; };

x1 <- c('a','b');
x2 <- 'ab';
hinc(x1);
hinc(x1);
hinc(x2);

hget(x1);
## [1] 2
hget(x2);
## [1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [R package called `dict`](https://github.com/mkuhn/dict) that lets you use vectors as keys:

```
library(dict)
d <- dict()
d[[ c("a", "b") ]] <- 1
d[[ c("a", "b") ]]
```

This should be more efficient than deparsing the objects as previously suggested.

Comment: Thanks, looks very useful!  That is one feature I really liked in python.